# Не работает z-index, часть текста не прячется за картинкой

Tags: html, css

```
section{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

section img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

section img#moon{
    mix-blend-mode: screen;

}

section img#mountins-front{
    z-index: 10;
}

#text{
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 8vw;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: Пока что непонятно о чём речь, у меня вроде бы всё прекрасно прячется. Добавьте html-код и в целом составьте [mcve], из которого будет очевидно, кто где как не прячется

Comment: ну почему ж сразу не работает? может у вас просто картинка с прозрачностью :3 да и при... `MIX-blend-mode` прятать что-то перекрытием, мягко говоря странная идея, он вполне мог подмешать текст в картинку. он мешает вообще все подряд